# WYSIWYG editor doesn't allow more than two lines to be added

Tags: magento-2.1, uicomponent, adminform, wysiwyg

I have a text field in my admin form with WYSIWYG enabled and I am able to add limited content in it.
here is my uiComponent form field:

```
<field name="description">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">wysiwyg</item>
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">job</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string">Job Description</item>

                    <item name="template" xsi:type="string">ui/form/field</item>
                    <item name="wysiwyg" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">description</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">130</item>
                    <item name="rows" xsi:type="number">8</item>
                    <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>
```

Comment: The Problem was with the Database field length. one should use TEXT type of DB field for the WYSIWYG.